# How to set TinyMCE-Angular init config in angular5 component as opposed to the HTML?

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular5

I've installed the tinymce **angular** package which I can get working fine:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-angular

But I wish to change the init values within the component so I can load the skins link etc from a config per environment instead of hard coding this in the html.

I've tried:

```
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
```

and using:

```
tinymce.init({
    skins: '/assets/skins'
});
```

However this complains to do an npm install @types/tinymce (which I've already done but it's not seeming to recognise this package)

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? The documentation isn't great and I can't seem to find any help online after endless searching.

**Note**: I'm copying the skins from /node_modules/tinymce/skins into /assets/skins, so I just want a way of being able to point to this location for the editor to load them

Comment: If you have installed tinymce, try using `declare var tinymce: any;` instead of your import. You won't have intellisense, but you won't have the error either.

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks for the response, I've gave this a go and nothing happens :(

Comment: What does `nothing happens` mean : tinymce works but you don't have the skin ?

Comment: @trichetriche Sorry I mean tinymce doesn't work, it requires the skins to display, it's trying to find them at /skins/ rather than /assets/skins

Comment: Yeah you have a path issue. Try with `./assets/skin`, and go up until it works : `../assets/skin`, `../../assets/skin`, and so on

Comment: (And of course, be sure that it's how you set up tinymce)

Comment: I don't know enough about tinymce to tell you how to dit, sorry. Maybe the documentation would talk about it, and if not, don't hesitate to create an issue on their repository !

Comment: @trichetriche Ok no worries, thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some further investigation I found the answer to this question myself, so for clarity in case anyone else is struggling with a similar issue, here is how I solved it:

I first followed the instructions given here: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular

(Importing the module, and adding the editor to the component.html file)

Then within the component.ts I set the baseUrl and altered the init:

```
import 'tinymce';
declare var tinymce: any;

public ngOnInit (): void {
    this.setupTinyMce();
}

private setupTinyMce (): void {
    tinymce.baseURL = 'assets';
    tinymce.init({
        skin_url: '/skins' // Or loaded from your environments config
    });
}
```

You also need to copy the 3 Folders "plugins", "skins", "themes" from "node_modules/tinymce" to the "assets" folder 
(or use webpack or equivalent to do so for you)

Comment: thanx, the import 'tinymce' did it for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution has 2 problems:

- copy folders to assets is not great in production, because anybody can see the assets folder.
- tinymce has type any and is not nice in typescript

My solution:

Install @types/tinymce package

Copy tinymce script to index.html head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/{token}/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
```

than in your component:

```
import { OnInit, Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { TinyMCE } from 'tinymce';

declare const tinymce: TinyMCE;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-editor',
    templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editor.component.scss'],
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            tinymce.init(editorConfig);
        });
    }
}
```